# How can i add string at the beginning each line?

Tags: python, file

I need to add at beginning of each line id from a list five times.
`file_id` like

```
5
8
6
9
```

`text_file` like

```
pla pla pla 
text text text 
dsfdfdfdfd
klfdklfkdkf
poepwoepwo
lewepwlew
```

the result should be

```
5 pla pla pla 
5  text text text
5  dsfdfdfdfd
5  klfdklfkdkf
5  poepwoepwo
8  lewepwlew
```

and so on .. the number of ids equals 5000 ids and text equals 25000 sentences .. every id will be with five sentences. i tried to do something like that

```
import fileinput
import sys   
f = open("id","r")
List=[]
for id in f.readlines():
    List.append(id)    
file_name = 'text.txt'    
with open(file_name,'r') as fnr:
    text = fnr.readlines()
i=0
text = "".join([List[i]+" " + line.rstrip()  for line in text])    
with open(file_name,'w') as fnw:
    fnw.write(text)
```

but got results

```
 5
 pla pla pla5
 text text text5
 dsfdfdfdfd5
 klfdklfkdkf5
 poepwoepwo5
 lewepwlew5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:  I haven't tested it yet though

```
lst = []
with open("id","r") as f:
    ids = f.read().split('\n')
    file_name = 'text.txt'
    with open(file_name,'r') as fnr:
        text = fnr.read().split('\n')
        counter = 0
        for id_num in ids:
            for _ in range(5):
                if counter >= len(text):
                    break
                lst.append(id_num + " " + text[counter])
                counter += 1

text = '\n'.join(lst)
with open(file_name,'w') as fnw:
    fnw.write(text)
```

output:

```
1 pla pla pla
1 text text text
1 dsfdfdfdfd
1 klfdklfkdkf
1 poepwoepwo
2 lewepwlew
2
```

Comment: i got `lst.append(id_num + " " + text[counter]) IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @sammo  I just fixed that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
i=0
text = "".join([List[i]+" " + line.rstrip()  for line in text])
```

You can try:

```
new_text = []
for i, line in enumerate(text):
    new_text.append(List[i % 5] + " " + line.rstrip())
```

And then write `new_text` to the file.

Comment: i tried it but the file didn't open yet